# Is it possible to get turicreate to run on an AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, turi-create

I haven't had any trouble getting `turicreate` to run on my Ubuntu OS - however when deploying to an AWS EB instance (Python 3.6) I get the error: `ImportError: libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

This is clearly a problem with not completing the setup instructions found [here](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/blob/master/LINUX_INSTALL.md).

So I tried to update my `/.ebextensions/setup.config` to resemble the following to try to update the environment so `turicreate` can run.

```
packages:
  yum:
    libstdc++6: []
    python-setuptools: []
```

I needed to use `yum` because the AWS instance doesn't have `apt-get`. However this comes with its own errors: `Activity execution failed, because: Yum does not have python-setuptools available for installation (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)` and `Activity execution failed, because: Yum does not have libstdc++6 available for installation (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)`.

If I **ssh** into the environment...

```
[ec2-user@ip-***-**-**-*** ~]$ sudo yum install -y libstdc++6 python-setuptools
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                           | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                        | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
No package libstdc++6 available.
Package python26-setuptools-36.2.7-1.33.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[ec2-user@ip-***-**-**-*** ~]$
```

What's going on here? How can I configure the EB instance to run `turicreate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turicreate can run on AWS instances but you have to install the dependencies using Yum. Yum has different file names and the following install config should work.

```
packages:
  yum:
    blas-devel : []
    lapack-devel: []
```